# generating traffic for HTTP1 and HTTP2

Tags: http, wireshark, http2

I need to generate traffic for let say http(s)://abc.com for both HTTP1 and HTTP2 for which I am using fidller and with some twist wireshark(for HTTP2 decrypted) respectively.
But I have to visit the application/site twice to generate the traffic for both the protocol.
As far as I know once you start fidller it will force the traffic to HTTP1 so I can not generate network capture in parallel with wireshark for HTTP2.
Is there any way to visit site only once and generate HTTP1 and HTTP2 traffic in one go with fidller and wireshark???
Thanks in advance!!!

I try running both the tools in parallel but no luck!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to generate the http1 and http2 traffic in one go... if I am visiting the abc.com which is by default http2 traffic....
I should be able to generate the http1 and http2 traffic parallel...and capture it.